# Spark-Kafka integration Exception: GroupAuthorizationException

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka

I am trying to get data from Kafka to HDFS using Spark-Streaming. 
I dont have any access to Kafka Queue as it is handled by different team. Hence I am not aware of their internal configs

At first, it runs fine. But when it reconnects after a while somehow "spark-executor-" is prefixed to the group id.
SO the group id "ABC" becomes "spark-executor-ABC"
I dont understand why.

The kafka queue is using SSL without Kerberos

Following is the error

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 2.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 3, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.kafka.common.errors.GroupAuthorizationException: Not authorized to access group: spark-executor-ABC
```

Kafka Version:0.11.0.3
Spark Vesion: 2.2.0:2.11

dependencies:
spark-streaming-kafka-0-10-assembly_2.11
spark-streaming_2.11
spark-core_2.11
kafka_2.11

Following is the Kafka config:

```
val kafkaParams = Map[String, Object](
"bootstrap.servers" -> "XXX:XXX",
"key.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
"value.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
"group.id" -> "ABC",
"auto.offset.reset" -> "latest",
"enable.auto.commit" -> "false",
"security.protocol" -> "SASL_SSL",
"sasl.mechanism" -> "PLAIN",
"ssl.truststore.location" -> "XXXX",
"ssl.truststore.password" -> "XXXX")
```